# Show only children of current mouseover div :jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have categories that have children subcategories, the first time all subcategories children are invisible, I want when I pass the mouse over the category number the subcategory of this current category display and when I locate the mouse they return invisible

Html:

```
<ul class="product-categories">
   <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
      <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Baby</a>
      <ul class="children" style="display: none">
         <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
            <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Baby Girl</a>
            <ul class="children" style="display: none">
               <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
               <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Bodysuits</a></li>
        </li>
            </ul>
        <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
            <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Baby Boy</a>
            <ul class="children" style="display: none">
               <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
      <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href=">Boy</a>
   </li>
   <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
      <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Girl</a>
      <ul class="children" style="display: none">
             <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Shoes</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
      <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Nursery Furnishings</a>
      <ul class="children" style="display: none">
          <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Pushchairs &amp; Prams</a></li>
         <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Pushchairs's accessories&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Travel accessories</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(".cat-parent").on("mouseover", function () {
  jQuery( this " .children" ).css({'display': "block"});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector in incorrect. You need to use `$(".children", this)` or `.find()` to do this work.

```
jQuery(".children", this).css({'display': "block"});
// Or
jQuery(this).find(".children").css({'display': "block"});
```

Also you can use `mouseout` event to hiding elements after mouse out.

```
jQuery(".cat-parent").on("mouseover", function () {
  jQuery(".children", this).css({'display': "block"});
}).on("mouseout", function(){
  jQuery(".children", this).css({'display': "none"});
});
```

```js
jQuery(".cat-parent").on("mouseover", function () {
  jQuery( " .children" , this).css({'display': "block"});
}).on("mouseout", function(){
  jQuery( " .children" , this).css({'display': "none"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-categories">
  <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
    <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Baby</a>
    <ul class="children" style="display: none">
      <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
        <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Baby Girl</a>
        <ul class="children" style="display: none">
          <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
          <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Bodysuits</a></li>
          </li>
    </ul>
  <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
    <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Baby Boy</a>
    <ul class="children" style="display: none">
      <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
  <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href=">Boy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
    <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Girl</a>
    <ul class="children" style="display: none">
    <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Shoes</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item  cat-parent">
    <span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Nursery Furnishings</a>
    <ul class="children" style="display: none">
    <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Pushchairs &amp; Prams</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Pushchairs's accessories&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item "><span class="icon-toggle"></span><a href="">Travel accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: but when i move mouse the other subcategorie stay visible

Comment: @AhmedGuesmi Check it again

Comment: thank's a lot ;D this work , please i Have another question , as you see the children also have children can i don't display them ? like I do when selector ('.cat-parent > children')

Comment: @AhmedGuesmi `$('.cat-parent > .children')` select direct child of `.cat-parent`. You should use `$('.cat-parent .children')` if you want to select all `.children` child

Comment: yes I want to display only child not the child of child , how?

Comment: @AhmedGuesmi So you should use `$('.cat-parent > .children')`

Comment: how I can use it with your solution?

Comment: @AhmedGuesmi You should use `.children()` instead of `.find()` Check http://jsfiddle.net/y41bdsxg/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you'd handle this with CSS only. There's no need to use JavaScript to handle what you want to do.

I will assume that you want to display the subcategories when the user moves the mouse over the `.cat-parent` element. The following style will do the job:

```
.cat-parent:hover ul.children {
  display:block;
}
```

To break it down. This selector means that any `ul` element with the class of `children`, that is nested within an element with the class of `.cat-parent`, will get the above styling when the `.cat-parent` element is being hovered (hover is basically the same as mouseover.)
And as soon as you pull the mouse away from the element, the `:hover` sub selector disappears, and the `display` goes back to `none`.

So you wouldn't need the jQuery code. You only need to add the above style in your CSS file (or in a style tag on in the HTML file if you do not use any CSS file.)

A great bonus with handling this kind of design logic with pure CSS is that it works even on browsers that have JavaScript turned off.